# How to reference image in AXML in Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to point to images stored under `Resources/drawable` folders in the android screen design file with extension `AXML`.

So I pointed to the image like this `<ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_less_black" />`

But I am now getting an error that says

> Warning: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with
>   value '@drawable/ic_expand_less_black').

What am I doing wrong? My plan is to point to the image at various resolutions in the `drawable` folder.